# How to fill a box2d-qml polygon with a color?

Tags: box2d, polygon, qml

I have box2d and qml working together nice.
I am generating a polygon like this

```
Polygon{
    vertices: [
                Qt.point(6, 22),
                Qt.point(10, 64),
                Qt.point(46, 89),
                Qt.point(82, 64),
                Qt.point(84, 21),
                Qt.point(45, 1)
            ]

}
```

but can not add

```
Polygon{
        ...
        ...
     **color: red**   
    }
```

it does not allow with a red line under "color".

should i do some javascript attraction?

thanks

Comment: i found out that i can use gradient, but there is a bigger problem, my poligons are transparent, i can feel that they are there with physical attractions, but i can not see them. are there some opacity setting?

Comment: you must add image or object such as rectangle or circle, box2d object can not be colored

Answer (score 0):

you have to use hexadecimal colors.
or using Common.b2Color object.
you can see documentation here http://www.box2dflash.org/docs/2.1a/reference/

```
color : #FFFFFF;


or b2Color(rr:Number, gg:Number, bb:Number);
```